# python & pandas - Drop rows where column values are index values in another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The Original DataFrame(`df1`) looks like:

```
  NoUsager Sens NoAdresse Fait  Weekday NoDemande  Periods
 0 000001   +    000079    1     Dim   42191000972 Soir 
 1 001875   +    005018    1     Dim   42191001052 Matin 
 2 001651   +    005018    1     Dim   42191001051 Matin 
 3 001486   +    000405    1     Dim   42191001250 Matin 
 4 002021   +    005712    1     Dim   42191000013 Matin 
 5 001975   +    005712    1     Dim   42191000012 Matin 
 6 001304   +    001408    1     Dim   42191000371 Matin 
 7 001355   +    005021    1     Dim   42191000622 Matin 
 8 002274   +    006570    1     Dim   42191001053 Matin 
 9 000040   +    004681    1     Dim   42191002507 Soir
```

I used `crosstab` to generate a new one(`df2`) with `index = NoDemande, NoUsager, Periods` and `columns = ['Sens']`:

```
                       Sens  + - 
NoDemande  NoUsager Periods
42191000622 001355  Matin    1 2 
42191000959 001877  Matin    1 2 
42191001325 000627  Soir     1 2 
42191001412 000363  Matin    1 2 
42191001424 000443  Soir     1 2 
42191001426 001308  Soir     1 2 
42191002507 000040  Soir     2 0 
42193000171 000257  Soir     1 2 
42193000172 002398  Soir     1 2
```

I want to drop all the rows from `df1` where values in columns `NoUsager` and `NoDemande` are the same as the one in index `NoUsager` and `NoDemande` in `df2`. So the result will return a new DataFrame`df3` with the same `df1` format  but without `line7` and `line9`.

I tried:

```
df3 = df1.loc[~df1['NoDemande','NoUsager'].isin([df2.NoDemande,df2.NoUsager])]
```

But it returned: `KeyError: ('NoDemande', 'NoUsager')`

How can I solve this problem?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cols = ['NoDemande','NoUsager']
mask = df1[cols].isin(df2.reset_index()[cols].to_dict('list'))
df1[~mask.all(1)]
```

[image]

---

There were three things you were doing incorrectly.

1. `df1['NoDemande','NoUsager']` needs to be `df1[['NoDemande','NoUsager']]`
2. `df2` has index levels with names `['NoDemande','NoUsager']`.  You must reset the index to turn them back into columns.
3. When using `isin` for this purpose, transform `df2.reset_index()[['NoDemande','NoUsager']]` into a dictionary.

Comment: Nice answer. However, is there any reason not to do `df[['NoUsager', 'NoDemande']].isin(df2.reset_index()[['NoUsager', 'NoDemande']]).all(axis=1)`? What does the `to_dict` give here?

Comment: @AmiTavory yes, against my intuition, what you propose, doesn't work.  I'll try to write up something explaining why.

Comment: @piRSquared Thanks for this nice answer. So, it's impossible to compare columns and index?

Comment: @ch36r5s I wouldn't  say that, just not the way you tried it.  There are many ways to compare and index to columns.